# integer-matching regex pattern not working

Tags: c++, regex

I try to check whenever the input string is an integer, but nothing returns positive result with the pattern I created.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input = "1";
    string int_num = "^0$|^[1-9][0-9]*$";

    regex pattern(int_num, regex_constants::grep);

    if(regex_match(input, pattern))
        cout << "matched\n";
    else
        cout << "not matched\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `\d+` would stand for atleast one digit.

Comment: Your `regex_constants::grep` option is [causing the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30307990/477563).  If you remove the option or replace it with `regex_constants::ECMAScript` then it works correctly.

Comment: @Mr. Llama, it probably doesn't work because I use gcc 4.8. I have problems installing gcc 4.9, but once I got it, I will post the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, regex pattern should be changed to `"^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$"` because it looks better. Then, change `regex_constants::grep` to `regex_constants::ECMAScript`, or leave blank, because ECMAScript is default. At the end, it is required to compile with **g++-4.9**, because g++-4.8 version doesn't work with regex lib.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your pattern doesn't work is because you've specified that the regex should emulate `grep`s grammar.

If you remove that flag from your regex definition, your pattern works correctly:

```
string int_num = "^0$|^[1-9][0-9]*$";
regex pattern(int_num);
```

Here's an example of the modified script: https://ideone.com/iETnsw

If you must specify a regex grammar, use `ECMAScript`, not `grep`.

Comment: In your code, g++ c11 throws an error at first pattern compilation.

Comment: Okay, *what* error?  Have you tried specifying `regex_constants::ECMAScript`?

Comment: Without regex_constants and with regex_constants::ECMAScript error number 4 is thrown, but I don't know what it means.

Comment: You should probably display `e.what()`.  It contains [the actual error message](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_error).

Comment: Doesn't validate negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me,  although your version also seems to be correct according to ECMAScript regex syntax.

```
"^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$"
```

Comment: Could you please tell me why this patter works, but mine doesn't? And why my pattern works on regex101.com?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript says that | Separates two alternative patterns or subpatterns. If I understand this correctly, your version should work also, but it seems I do not.

Comment: @simon - That's what I saw too.  After playing around with it, it seems that using anchors (`^` and `$`) as well as a pattern separator (`|`) leads to unexpected results.  For example, not even `.*|^[1-9][0-9]*$` matches.

Comment: I must uncheck this answer, because this pattern, for some unknown reasons, accepts ONLY 1 character (1,2,3, ... even letters like 'a' or '$').

Comment: right, also the ECMAScript link is not relevant here, since you use grep syntax.

Comment: @simon wouldn't `"^([0-9]+)$"` work the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com), you can tell that your expression is not matching numbers. You can match a number by using the expression `\d+`.

Another way of verifying integers, would be doing something like this:

```
int y;
cin >> y;

if (cin.fail()) {
    //Is not an integer
}
```

Comment: Try your technique with this input: 123apple.  Did it succeed or fail?

Comment: I have used regex101.com, and my expression works there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to iterate through each character to check if they are digit and if it reaches the end, then it is a number. Maybe somwthing like would help. Haven't tested though.

```
string::const_iterator it = str.begin();

while(it != str.end() && isdigit(*it))
{
    it++;
}

if (!str.empty() && it == str.end())
    cout << "not a string";
else
    cout << "valid";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the grammar specification as grep, then it will work.

int main()
    {
        std::string input = "1";

```
    std::regex pattern ("^0$|^[1-9][0-9]*$");

      if(regex_match(input, pattern))
        cout << "matched\n";
    else
        cout << "not matched\n";

    return 0;
}
```

output: matched

Comment: I compiled with clang and gcc `clang++ -std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out` It is working. Am I missing any parameters?