# C++ std::stod. How to make user enter a number?

Tags: c++

I have a code I am having the user enter a weight for shipping. I am converting this number to a double for math and it works perfect using std::stod(); The issue comes when the user does not enter a valid entry. I am new to C++ and in C# I used try parse. How can I have a loop that will ask the weight until the user enters an actual number that can be switched into a double?

I am sure it is a basic questions, and I apologize if it is!

Comment: You can test for invalid argument exception: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/invalid_argument/

Comment: It'd help to show the code you are currently using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stod` function throws an exception when it does not parse correctly. So you could write:

```
double d;

for (;;)
{
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    if ( !std::cin )
        { d = 0; break; } // or some other handling that exits the loop

    try
    {
        d = std::stod(s); 
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid input, try again.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Carlos (if you read this) - I'd suggest posting your own answer given the significance of the suggested changes

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to enter the value into the string first. You can simply read directly into the double. If the user input value wasn't a double, then it makes the stream used to check the value invalid, and you can check that:

```
double
    translatedNumber;
if(input >> translatedNumber){
    std::cout << "number is " << translatedNumber << '\n';
}
else{
    std::cout << "invalid input\n";
    input.clear();

    // get rid of the invalid input in the stream
    std::string inputEater;
    input >> inputEater;
}
```

Or you can read in the string, and try to translate that. `stod` indicates errors by throwing exceptions, and you can catch the exceptions it throws and deal with them appropriately:

```
std::string
    userInput;
double
    translatedNumber;

input >> userInput;
try{
    // stod throws either invalid_argument or 
    // out_of_range if it can't convert the string
    translatedNumber = std::stod(userInput); 
    std::cout << "number is " << translatedNumber << '\n';
}
catch(std::invalid_argument &){ 
    std::cout << "invalid input\n";
}
catch(std::out_of_range &){
    std::cout << "input out of range representable by doubles\n";
}
```

In both of these examples, the `input` variable is used as a substitute for the `std::cin` variable, because I'm using the online compiler Coliru for the examples.

The live demo of both of these possible solutions is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3934b5ef4194ec01), and as you can see the output of the two approaches is:

first:

```
13 -> number is 13
banana -> invalid input
```

second:

```
4023.9 -> number is 4023.9
sandwich -> invalid input
43e508 -> input out of range representable by doubles
```

Answer (score 0):

one way you can do this:

```
    std::regex pattern ("^0$|^[1-9][0-9]*$");

      if(regex_match(input, pattern))
        cout << "matched\n";
    else
        cout << "not matched\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Other way you can do this:

```
string::const_iterator it = str.begin();

while(it != str.end() && isdigit(*it))
{
    it++;
}

if (!str.empty() && it == str.end())
    cout << "not a string";
else
    cout << "valid";
```

I'm helping you using this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306993/integer-matching-regex-pattern-not-working)

Comment: eUGh. I've never understood why, but regex patterns have just always looked so terrible to me.

Comment: when you create RegEx at your own, they'll look so terrible to you. man why you are re-inventing wheel. when you found a one just use it.
i.e don't create Regex just use existing solution. view the link and just use it.
[RegEx](http://www.regexr.com/)

Comment: RegEx are the best solution. even if you are using a built in function it is also using RegEx at the bottom line.

Comment: ... if you had done any lower-level work you would know how false that is. Maybe in some scripting languages or more abstracted libraries. But not the standard library C/C++ functions.

Comment: by lower level you mean Assembly, C, C++ they compare things at machine level ? then you are right this time. but C++ cx (2011) standard resembles c# :)

Comment: Also, if I wanted to write a parser for my own programming language; how would I do that with regular expressions without writing my own? If I had to parse each individual token with a separate regular expression, all of the usefulness of using regular expressions would be gone.

Comment: first find existing solution if not found then build your own.

Comment: C++CX is a managed microsoft-created off-shoot of standard C++. C# is a perfect example of a language where standard library things might be implemented with regular expressions (but I doubt it). Regular expression parsing is a **lot** slower than the procedural approach.

Comment: Well, it mimics the managed C++/CLI; but I don't think it's actually managed

Comment: well I wasn't aware of what ever you said in last comments.
you're saying right man. RegEx are slower.